# Reading output of blocking process

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-process

I have some simple application:

```
//first.exe

int main()
{
  std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "3" << std::endl;

  std::cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

And I want to invoke a callback in separate application when "2" occurs in  stdout of application run as a child process:

```
//second.exe

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_context context;
  boost::process::async_pipe out(context);
  boost::asio::streambuf buffer;

  boost::process::child("first.exe", boost::process::std_out > out);

  boost::asio::async_read_until(out, buffer, "2", [](boost::system::error_code code, std::size_t size)
  {
    //do something
  });

  context.run();

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I have to press any button in parent process due to `std::cin.get()` in child process to make io_context execute callback function. Do you have any suggestions to make it work as intended?

Comment: Use a pipe for standard input as well, and only write a single newline to that pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I don't think you need to do a thing (the `std::cin` read might just fail):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86e3c787aa6e88fc)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    bp::async_pipe out(context);

    bp::child c("./first.exe", bp::std_out > out);

    boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    boost::asio::async_read_until(out, buffer, "2", [&](boost::system::error_code code, std::size_t size) {
        if (code) {
            std::cerr << "Oops: " << code.message() << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "received: " << size << " bytes: ";

            auto b = buffers_begin(buffer.data()), m = b+size, e = buffers_end(buffer.data());

            std::clog << std::quoted(std::string(b, m)) << std::endl;
            std::clog << "Note that we read more bytes: " << std::quoted(std::string(m, e)) << std::endl;

            buffer.consume(size);
        }
    });

    context.run();
    return c.exit_code();
}
```

Prints

```
received: 3 bytes: "1
2"
Note that we read more bytes: "
3
"
```

### Cleaner

For cleanness, you could simply close `std_in`:

```
bp::child c("./first.exe", bp::std_out > out, bp::std_in.close());
```

And to be proper, also add the context for async io:

```
bp::child c("./first.exe", bp::std_out > out, bp::std_in.close(), context);
```

Those all work (see [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb2aa012f0683495)).

## More complicated

What if you actually need to supply input to get output? Or you need to supply input based on the output? Then the commenter is right: attach a pipe to std_in (or have a buffer be written asynchronously).

### Sending a Fixed Buffer

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3e28a79b41ded38)</kbd>**

- first.cpp

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  int main() {
      using namespace std;
      string s;
      while (cin >> s)
          cout << "reversed: " << string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()) << endl;
  }
  ```
- main.cpp

  ```
  #include <boost/process.hpp>
  #include <boost/asio.hpp>
  #include <boost/process/async.hpp>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>

  int main() {
      namespace bp = boost::process;
      boost::asio::io_context context;
      bp::async_pipe out(context);

      std::string i = "hello\nwo2rld\n";
      bp::child c("./first.exe", bp::std_out > out, bp::std_in < boost::asio::buffer(i), context);

      boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
      boost::asio::async_read_until(out, buffer, "2", [&](boost::system::error_code code, std::size_t size) {
          if (code) {
              std::cerr << "Oops: " << code.message() << std::endl;
          } else {
              std::cerr << "received: " << size << " bytes: ";

              auto b = buffers_begin(buffer.data()), m = b+size, e = buffers_end(buffer.data());

              std::clog << std::quoted(std::string(b, m)) << std::endl;
              std::clog << "Note that we read more bytes: " << std::quoted(std::string(m, e)) << std::endl;

              buffer.consume(size);
          }
      });

      context.run();
      return c.exit_code();
  }
  ```

Prints

```
received: 30 bytes: "reversed: olleh
reversed: dlr2"
Note that we read more bytes: "ow
"
```

### Sending Dynamic Data

Both synchronously and asynchronously:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    bp::async_pipe out(context), in(context);

    bp::child c("./first.exe", bp::std_out > out, bp::std_in < in, context);

    boost::asio::write(in, boost::asio::buffer("hello ", 6));

    boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    boost::asio::async_read_until(out, buffer, "2", [&](boost::system::error_code code, std::size_t size) {
        if (code) {
            std::cerr << "Oops: " << code.message() << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "received: " << size << " bytes: ";

            auto b = buffers_begin(buffer.data()), m = b+size, e = buffers_end(buffer.data());

            std::clog << std::quoted(std::string(b, m)) << std::endl;
            std::clog << "Note that we read more bytes: " << std::quoted(std::string(m, e)) << std::endl;

            buffer.consume(size);
        }
    });

    boost::asio::async_write(in, boost::asio::buffer("wo2rld\n", 7), [&](boost::system::error_code code, std::size_t size) {
        if (code) {
            std::cerr << "Oops: " << code.message() << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "sent: " << size << " bytes: ";
        }
    });

    context.run();
    return c.exit_code();
}
```

Printing again:

```
sent: 7 bytes: received: 30 bytes: "reversed: olleh
reversed: dlr2"
Note that we read more bytes: "ow
"
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks. But now I am wondering what is the difference between cin.get() and getchar() because I tried first solution on both and it works only for cin.